# Force download php returns okb if there are spaces in the file name

Tags: php, path

I am trying to force download an mp3 file from a server using PHP.

I am using absolute paths for example `my-domain.../my-file.mp3`

This is the code that I am using to download the file.

```
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $_GET['name']);
  $path = urldecode($_GET['path']);
  if(isset($path))readfile($path);
```

If the file path has some spaces in it, it downloads a 0kb file and I have no idea why, I need help with this, so if the file path is `my-domain.../my-file.mp3` it works great. If it is like this `my-domain.../my file.mp3` it does download the file but it has 0kb.

I have tried everything I could think of but I can't figure it out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the filename contains spaces, you should output the name in qoutes like this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $_GET['name'] . '"');
```

Comment: I have fixed this issue, it seam that the URL has to be encoded properly using encodeURI or encodeURIComponent.

Took me a while to figure this out :)